# Does 1 volt cancel out 1 ohm? Can current be 0?

Tags: electricity

$V=IR$

Right?

$100 (\rm{V}) = 0 (\rm{A}) \times 100 (\rm{\Omega})$

Lets say something has $100 \rm V$ potential But since this object is surrounded by air and current is not flowing therefore there has to be $100 \rm{\Omega}$. Right? But then the equation does not work as 100 does not equal 0?

You get infinite resistance

Comment: The $V$ stands for potential **difference** across the resistance.

Comment: Resistance of air *is* very large.  Resistivity of air is $1.3\times 10^{16}$ to $3.3\times 10^{16}$ $(\rm{\Omega - m})$ at 20 celsius. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_of_various_materials

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question? If you take an equation, plug in arbitrary values the result is nonsense. It's like saying "we have a circle with a 1m diameter, but tiny area then, according to $a=\pi \cdot r^2$ we now that $\pi$ must be zero".

Comment: So your error is in saying 'since current is not flowing there has to be 100 $\Omega$ resistance'. You go on to show that this is nonsense yourself by finding that 100 $\neq$ 0 $\times$ 100! If no current is flowing, and there is some non-zero potential difference, then there must be _infinite_ resistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resistivity of a given substance (air) is fixed. For constant potential difference, current will change as $I=\frac V R$. However, air is not an ohmic substance so ohm's law does not apply for air.